# How to add text on the last element of a map with react

Tags: reactjs

I have a array

```
const data = ["red", "green", "blue"];
```

and I would like to display it in a map in order to add a comma to it but also for the penultimate element the text "And".

To obtain the following display: `"red", "green", and "blue"`.

I know the display that allows me to add the `comma` and the `""`.

```
  <div>
    {
      this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
        return <span key={`${index}`}>{ (index ? ', "' : '"') + item }" 
</span>;
      })
    }
  </div>
```

but I don't know the solution to add the word "and" before the last element in case there are several.

Do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean you want `"red", "green", "and blue"`? Putting the `and` outside the string delimiters doesn't make sense. Or do you mean `"red", "green", "and", "blue"`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I cannot add the word "and" in the table I reuse this same table for the display of a select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this solution I think it will help you out

```js
{this.props.data.map(function (item, index) {
          return (
            <span key={`${index}`}>
              {index!==this.props.data.length-1? (index ? ', "' :
 '"') + item : (', and "'+item)}"
            </span>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: Excellent and thanks. I got help from your good point about `this.props.data` instead `data`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the item is in the last position of the array, and accordingly append "and" to the string.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
          if (index === this.props.data.length - 1)
            return (
              <span key={`${index}`}>{(index ? ', and "' : '"') + item}"</span>
            );
          return <span key={`${index}`}>{(index ? ', "' : '"') + item}"</span>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={["red", "green", "blue"]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi. your answer is excellent. but `data` or `this.props.data`? I wrote my answer with `data` but I see @manoj answer used `this.props.data` so I edited the like that too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Borni.Mr answer.

```
<div>
 {["red", "blue", "green"].map(function (item, index) {
  if (index === ["red", "blue", "green"].length - 1)
   return <span key={`${index}`}>{` and "${item}"`}</span>;
  return <span key={`${index}`}>{(index ? ', "' : '"') + item}"</span>;
 })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

One way is using a `ternary conditional` for checking for the last item:

```
  <div>
    {
      this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
        return <span key={`${index}`}>
{ (index === this.props.data.length-1) ? ', and "${item}' : ((index ? ', "' : '"') + item) }" 
               </span>;
      })
    }
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the item is not the first element, check if the item is the last element. If it is, prepend the text `, and`. Otherwise, prepend the text `,`. Then, add the item surrounded by quotation marks.

```js
const App = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    {data.map((item, i) => (
      <span key={i}>
        {i !== 0 && (i === data.length - 1 ? ", and" : ",")} "{item}"
      </span>
    ))}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={["red", "green", "blue"]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```